# How do you calculate a rectangular wave from input values?

Tags: c#, signal-processing, waveform

Here's a picture to make it a little easier:

[image: square wave form from input values]

The blue line represents some input values that resemble waves with variable amplitudes and lengths. The y axis represents the values, the x axis represents time. Please note that there is quite some jitter in the wave. However, every wave has a certain minimum and maximum length.
The green line shows how the input values should be transformed.

**Please note:** The above picture is just a hand drawn example to explain the task. In an ideal case, the position of the rising and falling edges of the rectangular (green) wave are close to the blue waves average value. The height/amplitude of the green wave segments should match the values of the blue wave.

- How do you calculate the green line?
- Do you know of any C# libraries or algorithms to do that? I guess this could be a rather common task for electrical engineers, so there are most likely some common approaches available. If so, how are hey called?
- How would you approach this requirements?

Any advice that helps in getting started is welcome.

Comment: What determines when the green line transitions from low to high? Some of those transitions look pretty arbitrary

Comment: Your square wave isn't really a square wave. The title question is easy. The question from the picture is very different. Come up with some proper specs.

Comment: have a look at the descrete Fourier transformation (DFT) and signal processing in general:

http://fourier.eng.hmc.edu/e101/lectures/Image_Processing/node2.html / https://dsp.stackexchange.com/questions/9036/discretizing-a-continuous-time-signal / https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Discrete_Fourier_transform

Comment: Thanks for the quick feedback! Please excuse the lack of specification in the original post. I've updated the question. @Mär thanks for sharing these links!

Answer (score 1):

Take a base frequency (f) at an amplitude (a).

Then add ODD harmonics with the inverse amplitude ie f * a + f3 * a/3 + f5 * a/5 + f7 * a/7 ...

This will tend towards a square wave as you add harmonics.

BTW Try doing the same with even harminics, and with all the harmonics - Great fun!!!

Good luck

Tony